# String Allocation In C++

Tags: c++, string, memory

I was playing with the new and delete operators overloading when I noticed something strange.

1. I have:

   ```
   void* operator new(size_t size)
   {
       std::cout << "Allocating memory..." << std::endl;

       void* p = malloc(size);

       if (NULL == p)
       {
           throw std::bad_alloc();
       }

       return p;
   }
   ```
2. When I do:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       int* x = new int(1);
       std::cout << *x << std::endl;
       delete x;
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```

   Everything works as expected and I get:

   ```
   Allocating memory...
   1
   ```
3. But when I do:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       std::string* s = new std::string("Hello world");
       std::cout << *s << std::endl;
       delete s;
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```

   I get:

   ```
   Allocating memory...
   Allocating memory...
   Hello world
   ```
4. In fact, when I do:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       std::string s = "Hello world";
       return EXIT_SUCCESS;
   }
   ```

   I still get `Allocating memory...`!
5. Finally, I do:

   ```
   int main()
   {
       std::string s = "Hello world";
       std::cout << &s << std::endl;
       while (true);
   }
   ```

   To get something like:

   ```
   $ ./test &
   [1] 8979
   Allocating memory...
   0xbfc39a68
   $ cat /proc/8979/maps | grep stack
   bfc27000-bfc3c000 ... [stack]
   ```

   So now I'm sure the `s` variable is allocated on the stack... but then, what's calling the `new` operator? My best guess would be it has something to do with the memory allocation for the actual literal, `"Hello world"`... but it's supposed to be static memory, and `new` is all about dynamic memory.

What's going on?

## Update

After reading the comments and debugging the example myself I wanted to conclude that indeed, once the string constructor is called, it allocates memory on the heap for its internal implementation. This can be seen by tracing the `new` call:

```
(gdb) b 13 // that's the std::cout << "Allocating memory..." << std::endl; line
(gdb) r
... Breakpoing 1, operator new (size=16) at test.cpp:13 ...
(gdb) backtrace
#0 operator new (size=16) at main.cpp:13
#1 std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
...
```

And reading the std::string (well, [basic_string.tcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a00771_source.html)) source code:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits, typename _Alloc>
typename basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_Rep*
basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::_Rep::
_S_create(size_type __capacity, size_type __old_capacity,
          const _Alloc& __alloc)
{

   ...

    void* __place = _Raw_bytes_alloc(__alloc).allocate(__size);
   _Rep *__p = new (__place) _Rep; // Bingo!
   __p->_M_capacity = __capacity;

   ...

}
```

So yeah. Programming's cool.

Comment: note: `malloc`/`free` and `new`/`delete` - are pair

Comment: Why don't you use a debugger and break in your `operator new` to see who is calling it? Streams do allocate memory, too.

Comment: The whole point of `std::string` is that it wraps up a `char*` and own/manages it for you. So when you create a `std::string`, it allocates some memory to store the actual characters. The constructor can even take a custom allocator.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I also implemented `delete` via `free`, if that's what you mean, but it was irrelevant to the question, so I omitted it.

Comment: It's not the literal, the `std::string` class is performing memory allocation internally. The details aren't particularly important, but is a wrapper around C-style strings (nul-terminated arrays of `char`) that manages memory allocation for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
std::string s = "Hello world";
```

you are calling the constructor `string (const char* s);`, the specification of this constructor is `Copies the null-terminated character sequence (C-string) pointed by s.` So the constructor allocates memory to store the copy.

Comment: The *you* in the last sentence is confusing, it would better be phrased *So `s` need to allocate the memory to store the copy* but then I would advise you change the constructor parameter name since it is also `s`.

Answer (score 3):

Example 3.: (first note, that you have to ust `std::string *s` instead of `std::string s`, since `new` returns a pointer).

Using gdb i set a breakpoint at the std::cout line and backtraced the two calls:

The first one is the `new` you wrote in your code.
The second one happens to be called from within libstdc++.so.6 (in my case):

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  operator new (size=36) at test.cpp:6
#1  0x00007ffff7b78a89 in std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7b7a495 in char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7b7a5e3 in std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x0000000000400da1 in main () at test.cpp:20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  std::string s = "Hello world";
```

Right hand side is static memory 
`s` constructor allocates new memory and copies "Hello world",

Answer (score 0):

std::string is a structure that encapsulates a c-styled string.

A first allocation is made for the string container-structure.
A second allocation is for a copy of the string which is made in the string construction.

Answer (score 0):

The `string` object itself allocates space for the actual characters using `new`. This is done in the string's constructor.